# SQL Server audit logout creates huge number of reads

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-tuning, sql-tuning

I'm using SQL Server Profiler to figure out what process are consuming SQL process and I found that the event class `Audit Logout` is causing a huge number of reads and consume cpu process.

Is it normal? Or do I have something wrong in the SQL Server configuration?

Answer (score 32):

The audit logout event aggregates a lot of its values like reads/writes, connection times, etc. from the time the connection was opened.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175827.aspx - the definition for your specific question added here:

`Reads` `Number of logical read I/Os issued by the user during the connection.`

So basically, the number you are seeing is not for the audit event itself, it is for all actions done by the connection that is logging out.