# How to correctly read and interpret data displayed in SQL Server Profiler - What does duration tell me?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-profiler, sql-server-performance

I have a production web site that randomly hangs. I can't recreate it on test or dev servers. We therefore ordered a trace to be collected from the MS SQL Server.

When going through the trace, I noticed that sometimes, a very long duration were logged. I also noticed that the **[SPID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175827.aspx)** number changes every time this huge duration is recorded - see image. Is it a locked/hanging process that's unresponsive for the logged duration or how do I interpret this?

I've already been to the [TechNet Library](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175848.aspx) and [other sites](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/how-to-identify-slow-running-queries-with-sql-profiler/), but I can't seem to find the answer to this.

I'm afraid that I don't have the time to learn all there is about the matter or spend days finding the answer.

I'm really more in the need for a *Yeah, you're screwed!* or *Don't worry, that duration is just the time elapsed since that SPID had to access data!* or something like that.

I hope there's anyone out there able to help!

[image: Trace File Duration]

Comment: Related to: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132539/what-is-audit-logout-in-sql-server-profiler), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049452/sql-server-audit-logout-creates-huge-number-of-reads), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279401/sql-connection-pooling-and-audit-login-logout).

I'm thinking, more and more, that it is an aggregate of how long that specific connection has been open, but it would be great if someone could confirm this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can tell you that is what it is supposed to be:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175827(v=sql.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175827%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

It's not strange that the spid changes when there's a Logout event...that is the connection id.
It would be interesting to see if it corresponds to the beginning or end of your hang event.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you to begin: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

There are a couple of free e-books that will help you learn how to read Profiler traces as well.  [Red gate](http://www.red-gate.com/community/books/mastering-sql-server-profiler) has a really good one.

Comment: Thanks, but I've been there already. I've updated my question a bit to narrow down what I'm looking for.